# Displaying text over an image on hover with transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a fade transition with opacity (see my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4t6wge3/)) that will be shown when you hover the circle.

How do I achieve a pretty fade-in of the `myContent` element?

```
<div class="circle">
  <div class="myContent">
    <div class="name">Sasasaas</div>
    <div class="position">asfasfasfas</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS I'm using

```
.circle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  border-radius: 200px;
  background-image: url("http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/yogscast/images/c/c7/Pixel_face_eyebrow_raised_600x600.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/480?cb=20130529234139");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.circle:hover {
  -webkit-filter: none;
}

.myContent {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  /**position: relative;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0.5s;**/
}

.circle:hover .myContent {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below codes, add transition to `.mycontent` and set it's `width as 100%`, then add `padding-top:50%` thus by using `text-align:center` and `padding-top` it aligns your text to center of image vertically and horizontally.

```css
 .circle {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   border: 1px black solid;
   border-radius: 200px;
   background-image: url("http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/yogscast/images/c/c7/Pixel_face_eyebrow_raised_600x600.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/480?cb=20130529234139");
   background-position: center center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: contain;
   margin: auto;
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(50%);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 }
 
 .circle:hover {
   -webkit-filter: none;
 }
 
 .myContent {
   opacity: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 170px;
   text-align: center;
   padding-top: 50%;
   transition: 1s ease;
 }
 
 .circle:hover > .myContent {
   opacity: 1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="myContent">
    <div class="name">Sasasaas</div>
    <div class="position">asfasfasfas</div>
  </div>
</div>
```